# Python: Create list of items from CSV and find the max date for each

Tags: python

I am writing code that currently just scrapes news stories from a newsite and then stores the Date, Community, author, story, and image information to a CSV.

I want to be able to extract the 'last post date' for each community from the csv so that when I scrape again, I am only scraping new items vs items previously scraped.

So far I have a list that populates with each Community and Date for every entry.  What would be the best way to get the most current date for each Community, and is this the speediest way to do this...the file is pretty large, as it contains about 168k lines.

```
    import csv
    import datetime
import pandas as pd
    def community_last_dates():

dates_list = []
with open('testscrape.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_reader:
        date = line['Date'] + " " + line['Year']
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%B %d %Y').strftime('%Y %d %m')
        community_name = line['Community']
        dates_list.append(community_name)
        dates_list.append(date)

df = pd.DataFrame(dates_list)
df.columns = ["Community", "Date"]
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format='%Y %d %m').max()
grouped_by_community = df.groupby("Community")
recent_date_by_community = grouped_by_community.first()
print(recent_date_by_community.to_dict('index'))
```

Comment: What are you using the dates_list for?

Comment: Eventually it will be used to check against what the most current article date is.  So if in the file the most recent article for Community X is 2020-5-22, I would scrape the articles from say todays date all the way back the 2020-5-22 date.

Comment: Could you provide an example of `Date` and `Year`?

Comment: csv data looks like this...Date,Year,Time,Author,Summary,Community,ImagePath
December 31,2018,10:08 AM,text.,Wood Dale Crime,No Image

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with.  This creates a dictionary with the community name and dates correctly.  A dictionary worked better for a number of reasons.  Community Names are unique and will work as a key better than a list.

```
dates_list = []
with open('testscrape.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_reader:
        date = line['Date'] + " " + line['Year']
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%B %d %Y').strftime('%Y %d %m')
        community_name = line['Community']
        entry = community_name, date
        dates_list.append(entry)
    print('Completed')

df = pd.DataFrame(dates_list)
df.columns = ["Community", "Date"]
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format='%Y %d %m')
recent_date_by_community = df.groupby('Community').Date.max()
max_dates = recent_date_by_community.to_dict()

for k in max_dates:
    print(k, max_dates[k])
```

I made some mistakes with the group_by process in Pandas as well...
Originally I had this..

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dates_list)
df.columns = ["Community", "Date"]
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format='%Y %d %m').max()
grouped_by_community = df.groupby("Community")
recent_date_by_community = grouped_by_community.first()
print(recent_date_by_community.to_dict('index')
```

And while it looked correct, it only returned the greatest date in the file and assigned that to each community.  Here it is corrected...

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dates_list)
df.columns = ["Community", "Date"]
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format='%Y %d %m')
recent_date_by_community = df.groupby('Community').Date.max()
max_dates = recent_date_by_community.to_dict()

for k in max_dates:
    print(k, max_dates[k])
```

The dictionary output looks like this.

> {'Community 1': Timestamp('2025-10-09 00:00:00'), 'Community 2': Timestamp('2020-05-08 00:00:00')}